# SVN 1.7: How can I link some projects (folders) in working folder to different repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

After upgrading working folder from `svn` 1.6 to 1.7, all projects are linked to only one repository now.

But when it was `svn` 1.6, several projects in working folder were linked to different repository.

So now I can't link specified project to different repository, every project must be linked to one rep now...

How can I link some projects (folders) in working folder to different repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all explained in [the SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.externals). You're looking for *externals* definitions:

> Sometimes it is useful to construct a working copy that is made out of
>   a number of different checkouts. For example, you may want different
>   subdirectories to come from different locations in a repository or
>   perhaps from different repositories altogether.

[...]

> Fortunately, Subversion provides support for externals definitions.